# Why can I no longer mine on the binance pool?

Tags: mining, mining-pools, ethminer, binance, stratum

**This question was closed due to being off-topic, which is fair enough, but I'll  add the solution here in case it helps someone:**
Change protocol to `stratum1+tcp`.

I have been using the ethminer client to mine on the binance ether pool.

Around 24 hours ago (16:00 EDT Jun 10th), my worker's reject rate hit 100%
[image: Hash rate and reject rate chart]

Checking the pool stats at 21:00 EDT, this is what I saw:
[image]

Seemingly indicating that there was some kind of widespread issue affecting over half of the pool.

Checking the stats now, you can see that a majority has recovered.

[image]

Despite this, I am still getting the issue, and can't find any information about what's going on.

After checking the ethminer output, I noticed all solutions were being rejected. I tried restarting with my usual url:

> stratum+tcp://user.001:password@ethash.poolbinance.com:1800

And repeatedly got this error:

> Stratum got invalid Json message : BadHexCharacter

I then tried changing the protocol to stratum2, which stopped that error, but then all solutions were still rejected.

> Reject reason : Unspecified
>
> **Rejected  72 ms. ethash.poolbinance.com [172.65.8.243:1800]

This is the command I'm using to run ethminer:

> ethminer --cu-devices 0 -P stratum2+tcp://user.001:password@ethash.poolbinance.com:1800

Comment: The solution was to use protocol `stratum1+tcp`